# iTextSharp RenameField .Net sample?

Tags: .net, itext

I'm attempting to rename fields in a PDF in a .Net C# program using iTextSharp. I know there's already an old post with this problem, but I'm having the same issue and I'm not able to get the provided solution to work.
I've looked at Bruno Lowagie's sample renamefield.java program, but I'm using .Net C# and the objects do not have the same methods available as his sample.  Is there a .Net example?

Comment: Maybe you can't find the methods because you're using iText 7 and you're looking at the iText 5 exsmple, or vice-versa. We have written iText 7 from scratch to get rid of a significant number of annoying design choices that were made in the past. The iText 7 API is completely different from the iText 5 API.

Comment: You are correct!  I'm using iText 5 (iTextSharp 5.5.11) and I was looking at your iText 5 sample of RenameField.java.

Comment: Although I can now find the corresponding methods in .Net, they are organized slightly differently.  For example, in Java, the renameField method is: form.renameField("old_name", "new_name"); but in .Net it's:  form.Acrofields.RenameField("old_name","new_name");